# "Path login.page does not start with a "/" character" message exception after changing java version

Tags: java, struts

I have a web application which worked with the following:
Tomcat 5.0
Struts 1.0
Java 1.5

I have to switch to Java 1.6.When I tried to do that, i received the following stack of
exception in my browser:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Path login.page does not start with a "/" character
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:72)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:712)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:682)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:45)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:133)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:311)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:301)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:248)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path login.page does not start with a "/" character
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.handleAsForward(PerformForward.java:107)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.perform(PerformForward.java:96)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractPerformForward.execute(AbstractPerformForward.java:54)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:72)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:712)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:682)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:45)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:133)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:311)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:301)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:248)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77)
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a request is made to `"login.page"`, which as the exception indicates, does not start with a `"/"`. Try requesting for `"/login.page"` instead.

Most servlet libraries require that pathnames begins with a `"/"`. For example: [javax.servlet.ServletContext#getRequestDispatcher](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29):

> The pathname must begin with a `"/"` and is interpreted as relative to the current context root. Use `getContext` to obtain a `RequestDispatcher` for resources in foreign contexts.

Comment: Hi,
Well that is OK, because it works with java 1.5
The only problem is that i have upgraded to java 1.6

Comment: there must be another modif you did, @Hobbit Programmer. What have you changed other that the JVM ?

Comment: -so i have changed my env variables :
JAVA_HOME = path to jdk 1.6.0_18
-in IntellijIdeea ( this is my IDE) i simply switched from java 1.5 to java 1.6

If i switch back to jdk 1.5 everything works ok.

I haven't modified struts-config.xml, neither web.xml or other configuration file that might interfere.

Comment: After surfing google deeper, I have found this site :
http://marc.info/?l=struts-user&m=101768950326505&w=2 
where it stated to add a processor class in struts-config.xml

So I added :  
<controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/> 

Now the exception is gone, but I cannot login in,
When I try to do that it just reloads the same page.

Answer (score 3):

Check this page.

http://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsUpgradeNotes12to13

Obviously you're using stuts tiles. If you're using Struts 1.3, you should add this to your web.xml file:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>chainConfig</param-name>
    <param-value>org/apache/struts/tiles/chain-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: The site is blocked and needs a l/p.

Answer (score 1):

Solved

Whenever new Jsp file is added new entry goes in respective

"**struts-config_* .xml**" and "**tiles-defs_* .xml**" files.

Answer (score 0):

add the tile request processor class and remove the conten type attribute from controller tag

```xml
<controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor" />

<message-resources parameter="EMSMessageResources" null="false" ></message-resources>

<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin" >
    <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/ems-tiles-defs.xml" />
    <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
</plug-in>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add some more detail to you answer to show why it is correct?