# Turning URL into controller / action pair

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

In .Net MVC, you define routes into a `RouteCollection`. The URL helper methods make it easy to turn a `controller` + `action` + `optional params` into a URL.

When .Net MVC processes a request from a client browser, it clearly maps this URL to the right `controller` + `action`, to execute the appropriate command.

However, I can't see a way to programatically access this routing on the fly, such that I can turn a fully qualified URL (or a list of 10k+ URLs) into it's route components.

Does anyone know how you'd turn, for example, the following string **input**:

```
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342325/c-sharp-net-mvc-turning-url-into-controller-action-pair"
```

into the following **output**:

```
{
   controller: "questions",
   action: "view",
   id: 2342325,
   seoText: "c-sharp-net-mvc-turning-url-into-controller-action-pair"
}
```

Given this mapping is clearly being done by .Net, is it exposed anywhere?

**Why would anyone want to do this?**

Imagine you have a list of URLs you know have been accessed, mostly dynamic in nature, for example `stackoverflow.com/questions/2342325/c-sharp-net-mvc-turning-url-into-controller-action-pair`, and you want to work out which actual endpoints / actions / controllers are being hit programatically (without much care about the actual data being passed).

You *could* hand code mappings, such that you know `/questions/{id}/{text}` -> `controller: questions, action: question`, but that's not future-proof, nor is it fun, and relies on text manipulation / processing.

Given a Route Dictionary and a list of URLs, with a function as described above, you could look at which controllers are most hit, or which actions, etc.

Comment: Not clear why you want to, but you can use `Uri uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");` and inspect its `Segments` property

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Have added a "Why" to the question. But I presume the segments will just tell you the URL segments, without any care for the actual controller / action being called.

Comment: In your example, `Segments[0]` will return "questions" and `Segments[1]` will return `"ask"`, but that would only return the controller and method names if you have not created a special route for the method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'll update the example so it's clearer what I'm asking.

Comment: What you're asking isn't technically feasible. A URL only has meaning in conjunction with a particular route or set of routes which determine how the URL is parsed and what controller and action is initialized. For example, I could have a route that maps the URL "/foo/" to `MyAwesomeController.MyAwesomeAction`. In that case, there is absolutely no possible way you could simply look at the URL string and just *know* what controller and action will be invoked.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - not for a random project no, but where the Route Table is known, it should be trivial. Turns out it's not trivial, but possible (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only way to do this is by creating a dummy HTTP Context, similar to how you would unit test routes. It's a shame MVC doesn't provide better access to this, given it's being run on every request, rather than wrapping it up inside the context object.

Anyway, here is a working solution which can be modified to suit your needs:

```cs
public class UrlToRouteMapper
{
    public static RouteValueDictionary GetRouteDataFromURL(string absoluteURL)
    {
        var testUrl = "~" + new Uri(absoluteURL).AbsolutePath;
        var context = new StubHttpContextForRouting(requestUrl: testUrl);
        var routes = new System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection();
        MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);

        System.Web.Routing.RouteData routeData = routes.GetRouteData(context);

        return routeData.Values;
    }

    public static string GetEndpointStringFromURL(string absoluteURL)
    {
        var routeData = GetRouteDataFromURL(absoluteURL);
        return routeData["controller"] + "/" + routeData["action"];
    }

}

public class StubHttpContextForRouting : HttpContextBase {
    StubHttpRequestForRouting _request;
    StubHttpResponseForRouting _response;

    public StubHttpContextForRouting(string appPath = "/", string requestUrl = "~/") {
        _request = new StubHttpRequestForRouting(appPath, requestUrl);
        _response = new StubHttpResponseForRouting();
    }

    public override HttpRequestBase Request {
        get { return _request; }
    }

    public override HttpResponseBase Response {
        get { return _response; }
    }
}

public class StubHttpRequestForRouting : HttpRequestBase {
    string _appPath;
    string _requestUrl;

    public StubHttpRequestForRouting(string appPath, string requestUrl) {
        _appPath = appPath;
        _requestUrl = requestUrl;
    }

    public override string ApplicationPath {
        get { return _appPath; }
    }

    public override string AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath {
        get { return _requestUrl; }
    }

    public override string PathInfo {
        get { return ""; }
    }
}

public class StubHttpResponseForRouting : HttpResponseBase {
    public override string ApplyAppPathModifier(string virtualPath) {
        return virtualPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at creating your own [MvcRouteHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvcroutehandler(v=vs.118).aspx). This is the point in the MVC stack where the Route Engine has already parsed the URL to find which Controller and Action to call, and then it goes through this method to get the actual C# class and method to invoke. No authorization or even HTTP Verb has been applied yet, so you will see every call that is made to your application.

```
public class CustomRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext context)
    {
        var controller = context.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var action = context.RouteData.Values["action"];

        // Do whatever logging you want with this data, maybe grab the other params too.

        return base.GetHttpHandler(context);
    }
}
```

This can easily be registered where you set up your Routing.

```
routes.MapRoute("Home", "{controller}/{action}", new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index"
    })
    .RouteHandler = new CustomRouteHandler();
```

Comment: I'm trying to turn a string input (URL), into it's route components. Correct me if I'm wrong, but your answer is assuming there is a request to inspect? Imagine instead you have a list of 10k URLs, and want to see what controller / actions they map to in the current application, using the existing routing. Apologies if my question wasn't clear - edits welcome!

Comment: Your question is really unclear then. Why are you trying to inspect the URL _after_ it has been called? This is how you leverage the MVC framework to do that heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Because I have a list of URLs, and want to work out which controllers and actions they refer to... It's not to do with leveraging MVC during a given request, the question is whether it's possible to translate a string URL into an action / controller.

Comment: Is this within the same application? You could _try_ to instantiate a version of the Router you have running the website. The problem you're going to run into is that there's no guarantee that the route follows the `{controller}/{action}` layout. One could be set up `{action}/foo/{controller}`.

Comment: If it is your application that you are checking against, and you can't instantiate an instance of the Route Engine, the easiest would be to implement what I have in my answer, and write a console app that will iterate through your 10k URLs and call each and do it with leveraging MVC during the requests.

Comment: How do you instantiate an instance of the Route Engine such that a URL string can be supplied and return route data? That is essentially what I'm trying to do, and have only succeeded by stubbing out the httpcontext as per my answer. I assumed there would be an application level Route Engine which would simply map URLs -> actions (as must happen with every request). Similar to Url.Action(..), but in reverse.